# ASP.NET Identity email fields - possible to add multiple emails in one field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, microsoft-identity-platform

I have created an ASP.NET Web application using razor pages (not controllers) and this uses the Individual accounts from Identity.

The whole purpose of my site is that an admin logs in and uploads a document, they then press a button that sends an email to the receipting user to say they have a document to view.

I was wondering with microsoft identity, is there a possibility to use multiple emails? For example, putting a semi-colon between emails so that when the email is sent, it goes to multiple people.

[image: Registering a new user]

The code im using behind the button to send the email is as follows:

```
using (var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("ip address here"))
                                    {

                                        var emailMessage = new MailMessage();
                                        emailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
                                        emailMessage.To.Add(email);
                                        emailMessage.Subject = "New Document Avaialable!";
                                        emailMessage.Body = "You have a new purchase order available to view on the Portal!";

                                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
                                    }
```

Comment: What are you using for email validation? Any code could help us make a suggestion.

Comment: @MarcPfister I am just using the standard functionality that comes with Microsoft identity. If your asking for the code behind the button that I'm using to send the email i've added it into the post above.

Comment: The `To(string)` method takes a comma separated list of email addresses (not semicolon). See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.add?view=net-7.0#system-net-mail-mailaddresscollection-add(system-string). Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix as follows:

In the register.cshtml, there is an InputModel class that looks something along the lines of:

```
public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

First of all, I removed the [EmailAddress] from above the email.

Then instead of a semi-colon in the email text box, i put a comma between each email address and it worked.